# How to implement FacetSearchListener to add dynamic Solr filters in hybris?

Tags: java, solr, listeners, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on a project where I need to apply dynamic filter in the implementation of FacetSearchListener, before Solr query is executed, based on the request. How will I be able to distinguish the request in the listener class so that if else condition can be applied.

Comment: Could you please post some relevant code for your best attempt? Thanks.

Comment: Basically i want to pass the aCondition and bCondition to the listener from my controller in hybris. The sample code for the method in FacetSearchListener is :


@Override public void beforeSearch(final FacetSearchContext paramFacetSearchContext) throws FacetSearchException {
   
    if (aCondition) {
     paramFacetSearchContext.getSearchQuery().addFilterQuery("indexFieldA", "x");
    } else if (bCondition) {
     paramFacetSearchContext.getSearchQuery().addFilterQuery("indexFieldB", "y");
    }
   
   
   }

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but you can obtain the typed query by doing paramFacetSearchContext.getSearchQuery(). What exaclty do you want to check to decide whether to filter by one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

By implementing **YOURSearchListenerClass**

```
import de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.context.FacetSearchListener;

public class YOURSearchListenerClass implements FacetSearchListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeSearch(FacetSearchContext facetSearchContext) {
        facetSearchContext.getSearchQuery().addFilterRawQuery("YOURQuery");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterSearch(FacetSearchContext facetSearchContext) {}

    @Override
    public void afterSearchError(FacetSearchContext facetSearchContext) {}
}
```

And registering **YOURSearchListener**

```
<bean id="YOURSearchListener" class="YOURSearchListenerClass" />
```

And mapping **YOURSearchListenerDefinition**

```
<bean id="YOURSearchListenerDefinition" parent="solrListenerDefinition">
    <property name="listener" ref="YOURSearchListener" />
</bean>
```